# sql server - for loop - cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For the table below, I need to perform a loop operation in SQL Server 2008:

The column **Day** in the table can have values from 0 to 9.

```
For j = 0 to 9: (Iterate through the column **Day**)
   y=0;
   For k = 0 to 9:  (Iterate through the column **Day** again)
      if x[k] >= x[j]: y= y+1;
```

Table A:

```
Key|Day| x  | y |
---|---|----|---|
123| 0 |7000|   |
123| 2 |6000|   |
123| 9 |6500|   |
```

I have used cross apply and got the following:

```
select * from TableA A
cross apply (
select Day as k, case when B.x >= A.x then 1 else 0 end as y
from TableA B 
where A.Key = B.Key
) C
```

Output:

```
Key|Day|x[j]|k |x[k]|y |y - What I need
---|---|----|--|----|--|----------------
123|0  |7000|0 |7000|1 |1 
123|0  |7000|2 |6000|0 |1 
123|0  |7000|9 |6500|0 |1 
123|2  |6000|0 |7000|1 |1 
123|2  |6000|2 |6000|1 |2 
123|2  |6000|9 |6500|1 |3 
123|9  |6500|0 |7000|1 |1 
123|9  |6500|2 |6000|0 |1 
123|9  |6500|9 |6500|1 |2
```

Not able to figure out how to get y=y+1 for every k.

I am not allowed to use `join`. But if the performance of join is better than cross apply, please do share the solution.

Please help. Thanks

Edit:
I tried the following to calculate running totals with the condition:

```
select * from TableA A
cross apply (
select Day as k
,sum(case when B.x >= A.x then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by A.Key,A.Day) as y
from TableA B 
where A.Key = B.Key
) C
```

But it doesn't give me the correct output. I get:

```
Key|Day|x[j]|k |x[k]|y |y - What I need
---|---|----|--|----|--|----------------
123|0  |7000|0 |7000|1 |1 
123|0  |7000|2 |6000|1 |1 
123|0  |7000|9 |6500|1 |1 
123|2  |6000|0 |7000|3 |1 
123|2  |6000|2 |6000|3 |2 
123|2  |6000|9 |6500|3 |3 
123|9  |6500|0 |7000|2 |1 
123|9  |6500|2 |6000|2 |1 
123|9  |6500|9 |6500|2 |2
```

Also, when I use order by in the over clause it gives me an error:

```
The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.
```

Comment: Why aren't you "allowed" to use a `join`? A `cross apply` is also a "join" - a lateral cross join.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have a definite answer to that. The DB handles a high volume of transactions per minute. But the table on which I have to perform the above operation is only updated once a day so if the solution that uses `join` performs better, I will try to convince my "higher ups" about it.

Comment: You did right regarding cross join, but you're stuck with running total (last column). Try to search it.

Comment: You need a running total (with condition). SQL Server 2012+ can do it efficiently. In 2008 it may be more efficient to use cursor. Or calculate the running sum on the client.

Comment: Your latest query does give correct last column. What else do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. I'm running SQL Server 2016. The result should be the same. Note Key and Day column in your expected result don't match original data in TableA.

```
WITH TableY AS
(
    SELECT A.[Key], A.[Day], A.X AS xj, B.[Day] AS k, B.X AS xk, 
    (CASE WHEN B.X >= A.X THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y
    FROM @TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN @TableA AS B ON A.[Key] = B.[Key]
)
SELECT *,
    SUM(y) OVER(
         PARTITION BY [Key], [Day] 
         ORDER BY k 
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS 'RunningTotalY'
FROM TableY
ORDER BY [Key], [Day], xj, k;
```

Not sure how PDW error came from.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected TableA data so the results and the data matches. But this code doesn't work in SQL Server 2008. Works with SQL Server 2012 and above. So I'll have to use cursors like @Vladimir mentioned.